# TabView not showing properly on screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            Mapview()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Home")
                }
            
            AccountView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                    Text("Account")
                }
        
        }
        .accentColor(.white)
    }
}
```

My Screen is currently not showing the account icon on the tabview when I am on the MapView, also how do I change the colors of the icons to white because it only changes colors once I click on it right now.

I see it on my account page but not on the MapView, but the icon for home is dark and not visible on the AccountView, anyone know how I can make the icons appear for both screens.

Screenshot of Home Icon on MapView, unable to see Account Icon:

[image]

ScreenShot of TabView on Account Screen showing Home Icon dark:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the `init()` will set the color of the unselected item(s) to `UIColor.white`.  As for the selected item, use the `.tint` modifier and change the color to your preferred color (e.g. `Color.green`).  For the tab items themselves, below i have used a `Label`, but using `Image` and `Text` also produces the same output.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
        // Set the colour of the unselected tabBar items
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {

            Mapview()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
            
            AccountView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Account", systemImage: "person.circle.fill")
                }
        
        }
        .tint(Color.green) // The color of the tabItem that is selected
    }
}
```